# Exportar página web en producción

Tags: web, servidor, joomla3

He realizado una página web en joomla empleando xampp y ahora que la tengo terminada quiero subirla al servidor.

Básicamente he exportado el contenido de mi sitio web con la utilidad Akeeba Backup de joomla donde te genera un archivo con todo los elementos creados en la página.

Mis dudas son:

- ¿Debo instalar joomla en el servidor?
- Si no tengo el xampp instalado, ¿cómo puedo saber cual es el servidor web que tienen en el servidor instalado?
- ¿Cómo puedo saber en que directorio debo situar mi página?

Comment: ¿Has comprobado, para empezar, que tu servidor de producción soporta PHP y tiene los módulos necesarios para ejecutar la misma versión de joomla que tu entorno de pruebas? ¿Qué entorno de producción usas? ¿Has probado a subir los archivos del servidor xampp al servidor de producción y ajustar el archivo de configuración a los cambios? ¿Has exportado la base de datos del xampp e importado en el servidor de producción? ¿Has ajustado los archivos de configuración del joomla con los nuevos parámetros de host, usuario, contraseña y nombre de base de datos del de producción?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si utilizaste Akeeba Backup, todo lo que necesitas para instalarlo en producción es:

- Subir el o los archivos JPA generados por Akeeba al directorio raíz público de tu sitio web.
- Descargar [Akeeba kickstart](https://www.akeebabackup.com/products/akeeba-kickstart.html) y subirlo en el directorio raíz público de tu sitio preferiblemente (con otro nombre de archivo distinto al original)
- Ingresar por medio del navegador a Akeeba kickstart, por ejemplo: www.misitio.com/kickstart.php

Las otras dos preguntas solo las puede responder tu proveedor de hosting, nadie aparte de ellos tiene esas respuestas.

Comment: perfecto encontré ayer la solución al problema. El servidor es un IIS y tuve que actualizar la version del PHP y alguna que otra cosa mas pero ya esta todo arreglado. Gracias por el aporte ;D